# C# ReadAsByteArrayAsync result different from raw data and leads to file corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, multipartform-data, content-type

I am writing a file upload service using Resumeable.js(client) and C# MVC/WebAPI(Server).

On client side, Resumeable.js creates a blob for uploaded file and construct a multipart request to wrap some file information(name, size, etc) together along with the blob.

On server side, we use ReadAsMultipartAsync() to parse the multipart request and use ReadAsByteArrayAsync() to get byte from the file.

```
var parts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
...
// if parts contains file 
request.ChunkContent = currentPart.Contents.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

It works fine for plain text file, however, when I upload a 12kb .docx file using this file upload service, the byte array returned by ReadAsByteArrayAsync() is different from the raw file data, the first 16 bytes are the same and the size of the array increased to 18000+. 
I've checked that the bytes we sent to server are all correct in Fiddler.
Using utf-8 encoding doesn't fix the problem, does anyone have encountered same issue before?

Comment: Try await rather than .Result

Answer (score -1):

In my project I use the [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) framework, and recently I upgraded to version 2.6.0, and since then the problem has started.

If this is your case, just downgrade to version 2.5.0.

Comment: We are not using that framework, still don't know what is interfering with the data. We end up using 64 based string instead of raw binary data as workaround.